# Width calc() for fluid typography

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

Has anyone used calc() to develop fluid typography in email?

I'm playing around with ways to get fluid typography in emails (600px max) and vw doesn't seem to be do the trick since I need a range of screen sizes (otherwise it grows or shrinks beyond the point of readability). I suppose its because the viewport is the whole screen, but goes beyond the 600px email.

I'd use other techniques such as media queries, but as I'm sure many of you know, media queries and many other CSS stylings don't work on many email clients.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `.calc()` will work probably in "one" mail client.

Comment: Hmm, this [article](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/the-fab-four-technique-to-create-responsive-emails-without-media-queries-baf11fdfa848#.cig4xuk1u) seems to say it has pretty good support. And when there's no support (such as in Yahoo), I could insert a pixel font size as a backup (not ideal, but acceptable for what I want).

Comment: yes `.calc()` has decent support in email clients, almost as good as media queries. That's an interesting idea you're trying to solve! Have you gotten fluid typography to work using `.calc()` in either Apple Mail or Thunderbird (where you can adjust the `vw` and `vh`)? To at least prove the approach works?